# Array structure of questions with multiple right answers

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I'm writing a questionnaire app for iOS on xCode 5. I want to create an array of questions, but the thing is that each question has different number of answers and there are some questions where there are a few right answers.

For example:

Q1: The sky is...
A1: Green (Wrong)
A2: Blue (Correct)

Q2: The dog is a...
A1: Mammal (Correct)
A2: Reptile (Wrong)
A3: Pet (Correct)

I can't figure out how to create an array, or array of arrays for this. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *mainArray = @[@[@"Q1",@[@[@"A1",@1],@[@"A2",@0],@[@"A3",@0]]],@[@"Q2",@[@[@"A1",@1],@[@"A2",@1],@[@"A3",@0]]]];
```

so, the above mainArray contains entire data->

Firstly its an array of [question+answers]
i.e each object of mainArray contains `a question` and `corresponding answers array`.
And each answer array contains an array of `answer and a number` which says its correct or not.

so, if `number bool value` is 1, it means its correct answer, else if it is zero then its wrong answer.

So, for your case it will be

```
NSArray *mainArray = @[@[@"The sky is...",@[@[@"Green",@0],@[@"Blue",@1]]],@[@"The dog is a...",@[@[@"Mammal",@1],@[@"Reptile",@0],@[@"Pet",@1]]]];

//to get first question
NSString *question1 = mainArray[0][0];
NSArray *answerArrayForQuestion1 = mainArray[0][1];
//lets assume user selects answer as 2
//so to check whether its correct or not
NSInteger selectedAnswer=2;
BOOL correct=((NSNumber *)answerArrayForQuestion1[selectedAnswer-1][1]).boolValue; // which logs YES
```

Answer (score 2):

I know, everybody hates writing Object Oriented Code in Objective-C, but why not use an object oriented approach? Instead of using Dictionaries inside Arrays inside Arrays create proper classes and go for it.

```
@interface Question : NSObject
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *text;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *answers;
+ (instancetype)questionWithText:(NSString *)text answers:(NSArray *)answer;
@end

@interface Answer : NSObject
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *text;
@property (assign, nonatomic, getter = isCorrect) BOOL correct;
+ (instancetype)answerWithText:(NSString *)text isCorrect:(BOOL)correct;
@end
```

....

```
Answer *a1 = [Answer answerWithText:@"Mammal" isCorrect:YES];
Answer *a2 = [Answer answerWithText:@"Reprilte" isCorrect:NO];
Answer *a3 = [Answer answerWithText:@"Pet" isCorrect:YES];
Question *q = [Question questionWithText:@"The dog is a..." answers:@[a1, a2, a3]];
```